# React router shows up as undefined, how would I re-route to a certain page without using window.location

Tags: redirect, reactjs, routes

```js
var React = require('react');
var PropTypes = React.PropTypes;
var SearchStore = require('../stores/SearchStore.js');
var Router = require('react-router');

var SearchResults = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return( {searchResults: SearchStore.all()});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.searchResultsToken = SearchStore.addListener(this.newSearchResults);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.searchResultsToken.remove();
  },
  newSearchResults: function() {
    this.setState({searchResults: SearchStore.all()});
  },
  userDirect: function(id){
    window.location = '/#/user/' + id
  },
  songDirect: function(id){
    window.location = '/#/songs/' + id
  },
  playlistDirect: function(id){
    window.location = '/#/playlists/' + id
  },
  createSearchResults: function() {
    return this.state.searchResults.map(function(result, idx){
      if (result.username !== undefined){
        return <li key={idx} onClick={this.userDirect.bind(null, result.id)}>{result.username}</li>;
      }else if (result.genre !== undefined){
        return <li key={idx} onClick={this.songDirect.bind(null, result.id)} >{result.title}</li>;
      }else{
        return <li key={idx} onClick={this.playlistDirect.bind(null, result.id)} >{result.title}</li>;
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    debugger;
    return (
      <ul id='search-results'>
        {this.createSearchResults()}
      </ul>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = SearchResults;
```

The redirects when using window.location only work some of the time and aren't the general way you're supposed to do things in react, when I try to require the router it always shows up as undefined for some reason. I'm not sure why i cant require it, I saw somewhere else I would likely use a navigation mixin, but I'm still unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
// this is the redirect. Use it whereever you want
  this.context.router.push('/search');

// this should appear outside the element
    SearchResults.contextTypes = {
         router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
     };
     module.exports = SearchResults;
```